# C error:lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int hailstone(int n){ 
        int length=1;
        while(1<n){(n%2)?n=3*n+1:n/=2;length++;}//error
        //while(1<n){(n%2)?n=3*n+1:(n/=2);length++;} right
        return length;
}
int main()
{
        int n;
        scanf("%d",&n);
        printf("%d\n",hailstone(n));
}
```

There is an error in line four，the gcc compiler said **lvalue required as left operand of assignment**,but if i add brackets it will be right.like line five,and i don not know why.

Comment: There is really no good reason to cram that loop into one line like that. What's worse, it makes actually figuring out the problem *harder* for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite shoving all the logic into one line, the problem is actually in one expression (pardon me for adding spaces):

```
(n%2) ? n=3*n+1 : n/=2
```

The [precedence rules for C expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) are like that. Assignment (and that includes compound assignment) binds less tightly than `?:`. So the compiler has to interpret what you wrote as:

```
((n%2) ? n=3*n+1 : n) /=2
```

Since `?:` doesn't produce an lvalue (something that can appear on the left of an assignment), you get an error. Your use of parentheses forces the precedence to match what you wanted.

But an even better way to write that is to not be "clever" and think there is some "elegance" in using as much tokens as possible in a single expression. Here's another version, which is far more readable, and easier to verify as correct:

```
if (n%2) {
    n = 3*n+1;
} else {
    n /= 2;
}
```

And it's no less efficient than using a conditional expression.

Answer (score 0):

Here the compiler takes l value as

```
((n%2) ? n=3*n+1 : n) /
```

and r value as

```
2
```

Since `((n%2) ? n=3*n+1 : n) /` = `2` is an invalid statement and l value is not a variable, compiler throws error. You can provide the precedence of execution to the compiler by adding brackets.